# How to calculate the area and volume of a random 3d shape knowing only its coordinates?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, area, volume, collision-detection

Given a set of 3d points which make up an vector object of any shape (with any number of points), without the edges being known, how can the object's edges be found/detected so that the object's surface 3d area and internal 3d volume can be calculated?

Note: there may be points inside the object which do not form part of the outside edges.

Comment: It might not be obvious which points are in the ‘inside’

Comment: The term of art here is "[convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull)".

Comment: A best cost or worst cost edge finding function would be fine

Comment: @Blue thanks for that magic keyword!  once the convex hull is calculated, then would it be easy to know the surface area and internal volume?  Is there any special magic words for that too?

Comment: @Aalawlx: I don't really have anything more specific to add. Just search for "volume of convex polyhedron". So far as I know, there's no *good* formula, but there appear to be algorithms. See, for instance, ["Algorithm for finding the volume of a convex polytope"](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/979/algorithm-for-finding-the-volume-of-a-convex-polytope) on MathOverflow.

Comment: There is no simple answer here, but what many have done is to first triangulate the surface, that is, connect the points in such a way that the surface is made up of a number of connected triangles. The surface area can be found by adding up the areas of the triangles. The volume can be found by finding the normals to the triangles and applying Gauss's divergence theorem.